# How can I transcode US ASCII HTML's e.g. &eacute; to UTF-8's é undere Linux

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

What a quick web search will confirm that US ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, but what I've not yet found is how to convert &foo; and &#123; to their corresponding native UTF-8 characters.

I know that at least 7-bit US ASCII is unchanged in UTF-8, but I haven't seen yet a program to filter through and convert &foo; to how it would naturally be expressed in UTF-8.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you mean programmatically? But so we need to know the language (shell is considered a language). Note: you are mixing encoding (ASCII/UTF-8) with escape sequences and language representation. `&foo;` exists in ASCII and in UTF-8 and in many other encodings. Your examples seems HTML or XML, you should specify this in your question.

Comment: Is there a Linux command that will let me take a US-ASCII `input.html` containing e.g. `&alpha;` and output, to a file `output.html` or stdout, a UTF-8 output file where all instances of `&alpha;` have been replaced by `α`?

Comment: Maybe you can convert this into a programming question for, say, node, or move it to a power user or Linux SE site.

Comment: I do not think there is a good program. You need a HTML parser, or you risk to replace also in strings and other places (where it should not be changed). To me, it seems you are looking the wrong problem. Probably you should do such substitution after you get the data you need (e.g. when you extract titles, etc.) The keyword is `html entities` and there are not so many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `html_entity_decode(s, "UTF-8")` in PHP or `html.unescape(s)` in Python.

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape